# My accessor method returns null in Java but compiles without errors

Tags: java, oop

This is for a homework assignment and I'm totally stumped on this one.

```
public class Person {
String name;
int age;

public Person(String myName,int myAge) {
   myName = name;
   myAge = age;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getName() {
}

public void setAge(int newAge) {
   age = newAge;
}

public void printDetails() {
    System.out.println("The name of this person is " + getName());
}

public static void main (String[] args ) {
    Person Eliza = new Person("Eliza", 66);
    Eliza.printDetails();
}
}
```

This returns:

```
The name of this person is null
```

Hopefully I've missed something really obvious any comments are appreciated.

Comment: `myName = name;` should be `name = myName;`.

Comment: Your method getName() is not returning anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign myName to name and myAge to age, not the other way around and you are not returning anything in  getName().

```
public class Person {
String name;
int age;

public Person(String myName,int myAge) {
   name = myName;
   age = myAge;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setAge(int newAge) {
   age = newAge;
}

public void printDetails() {
    System.out.println("The name of this person is " + getName());
}

public static void main (String[] args ) {
    Person Eliza = new Person("Eliza", 66);
    Eliza.printDetails();
}
}
```

Comment: This is _at least_ the 3rd such question today about an assignment done in the wrong direction. Since they're doing it correctly in the setter, we can assume this was a "typo". Please don't get into the habit of answering such questions. Instead flag them with the close reason you can see above, and maybe drop a comment. We don't want to keep these questions around and an answer makes it harder to delete.